# Field and FieldAsync in GraphQL.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, graphql

I'm having some issues understand how I should write my code, I'm using dotNET 6 and GraphQL 7
I got told I have to use 'ResolveScopedAsync', but it's not a method of FieldAsync.
Another problem I'm getting with FieldAsync, is adding more than Argument, there is the definition of Arguments which accepts (theoretically) QueryArguments, but I tried in many ways to make it work, but always getting errors.
I'm not having issues at all using Field instead, because I can find ResolveScopedAsync and I can add more arguments, one by one, simply adding .Argument<NonNullGraphType>("postId")

Here is the code with Field, which is not giving me compiling error:

```
            Field<QuizResultType, QuizResult>("userQuizResult")
                .Argument<NonNullGraphType<StringGraphType>>("postId")
                .Argument<NonNullGraphType<BooleanGraphType>>("status")
                .ResolveScopedAsync(async context =>
                {
                    var user = await GetCurrentUser();
                    var moduleId = context.GetArgument<int>("moduleId");
                    var quizId = context.GetArgument<int>("quizId");
                    var quizProgress = await unitOfWork.QuizProgressRepository.GetUserQuizProgressAsync(user.Id.ToString(), moduleId, quizId);
                    return await moduleService.GetQuizResultAsync(quizProgress, quizId, moduleId);
                });
```

Here is what I tried to make FieldAsync work (but failed).
About Arguments:

```
FieldAsync<QuizResultType, QuizResult>("userQuizResult")
                .Arguments(new QueryArguments(
                    new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>> { Name = "moduleId" },
                    new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IntGraphType>> { Name = "quizId" }))
```

But doesn't work, it says 'It is not possible using as method the not recallable member FieldType.Arguments'.
Then FieldAsync doesn't have ResolveScopedAsync.

Any idea on how can I fix that?

Comment: In .NET 6, the API for defining GraphQL fields has changed, and some methods that were available in earlier versions have been removed or replaced. By using the GetRequiredService method from the IServiceProvider provided in the context, you can access the scoped services you need for resolving the GraphQL field.